# How do I get the bugs I'm seeing in empathy addressed?

Tags: bug-reporting, debugging

Since upgrading I'm seeing some extremely buggy behavior. I realize that its an ongoing software project and I don't expect everything to be perfect from day one but it's getting to the point that I would downgrade except for the apparent difficulty involved in that.

I get daily or so crashes from some background process telepathy...something. When I hit an intermittent internet connection I loose connectivity from all empathy chat services and can't regain them without rebooting. It occasionally prompts me to set up my accounts but selecting accounts/f4 doesn't bring up any windows. Also occasionally windows that disappear into minimized mode and are quite difficult to bring back.

Now I'm not against reporting bugs, but I feel like - besides clicking the "submit crash info" button over and over - I want to dig in a bit more. I would like to submit specifics t.

I'm sure there are forums, logs to submit, and people to pester. Where do I start?

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu folks use LaunchPad for this. The best guide for submitting bugs is here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs